# Add-In Error This add-in could not be started (randomly occurs after working fine for a while)

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have published our Outlook Add In to the AppSource store.  We randomly get customers contacting us saying that they get the error "This add-in could not be started. Close this dialog to ignore the problem or click "Restart" to try again.

There is nothing you can do to fix the problem once it occurs on a machine and it appears to happen randomly.  We have lots of customers who have no problems with the add-in at all.  We don't appear to have a way to troubleshoot this problem either or have any ideas why it is happening.

How can we trace it or fix it?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like your initialization code has an issue, please post the code where you're starting the add-in and I might be able to help you.

Comment: Which platform does this occur on, Windows / Mac Outlook or OWA?

Comment: We've noticed it on Windows with the latest versions of office 365 version of outlook installed.   I'll post the initialization code on Monday now.  Is there any logging we can check.